# MariaDB: is the page cache / buffer pool shared across database connections for an embedded database?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb-10.5

I have a multi-threaded (OpenMP) application using an embedded MariaDB database. Sometimes I use Aria and other times I use InnoDB. When I set the page cache buffer size for Aria (aria_pagecache_buffer_size) or the InnoDB buffer pool size (innodb-buffer-pool-size), will this memory be shared across all of the OpenMP threads for the embedded database? Or are they private for each connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InnoDB:

The buffer_pool is shared across all connections.  (From MariaDB's point of view, "connections" are significant; it does not care about what is going on in the client.)

How much RAM?  Keep in mind that Aria and InnoDB don't share much.  So you must split most of the memory between the buffer_pool and the pagecache.  A lot of the smaller things are 'common'.